# Printing this type of list

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I want to create a list like this:

```
mylist = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please explain what it is you want done.  Are you asking is there a way to create a list llike that (as in an increasing size string based on the alphabet) or is there a way to print a list like that?

Comment: Hey @ewong , thanks for your consideration! Yes I am asking to create a list that way and then print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def generate_list(start='a', end='d'):
    mylist = []
    start, end = ord(start), ord(end)
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        sublist = [chr(j) for j in range(start, i + 1)]
        mylist.append(''.join(sublist))
    return mylist

mylist = generate_list()
print(mylist)
```

prints

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

another example:

```
mylist2 = generate_list(end='f')
print(mylist2)
```

prints

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef']
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment but could you clarify? this is very confusing like do you want to print each item in the list?

Here's the code if thats what you want to do:

```py
mylist = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It doesn't. But I got answer to my question. Thank you for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format printing.

```
print("{} = [\'{}\', \'{}\', \'{}\', \'{}\']".format(mylist, varA, varB, varC, varD))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning appending letters to the list in alphabetical order and printing than out?

```
import string

n = 5
mylist = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    mylist.append("".join([letter for letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:i]]))
print(mylist)
```

will get result `['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde']`.

Or you could get each value by running

```
for value in mylist:
    print(value)
```